# Perl SOAP::Lite fix XML to be compatible with generated by PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, perl, soap

How can I make SOAP::Lite produce XML like PHP SoapClient does?

Example

Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use SOAP::Lite on_action => sub{sprintf '%s', $_[0]};
SOAP::Lite->import(+trace => "all");
my $client =  SOAP::Lite->new;

$client->service("https://www.just-example.test/dir/JustTest/Service.asmx?WSDL");
$client->proxy("https://www.just-example.test/dir/JustTest/Service.asmx");
$client->uri("http://example.test/ExampleMethod");

my %params = (
    'TestParam' => "",
     );
$client->ExampleMethod(\%params);
```

XML that is sent by the Perl code (seems to be **not** compatible with the service):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ExampleMethod
            xmlns="http://example.test/ExampleMethod">
            <c-gensym3>
                <TestParam xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            </c-gensym3>
        </ExampleMethod>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.just-example.test/dir/test/JustTest/Service.asmx?WSDL",
        array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'uri' => "http://example.test/ExampleMethod"

         )
);
$params = array (
    'TestParam' => ""
        );

$response = $client->ExampleMethod($params);

echo $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";

var_dump($response);
```

XML that is sent by the PHP code (seems to be compatible with the service):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://example.test/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ExampleMethod>
            <ns1:TestParam>0</ns1:TestParam>
        </ns1:ExampleMethod>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just change the prefix of the xml accordingly with your specification, take a look at similar question [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=701217) for more information .

To solve you particular problem I think you only need to put the following code at the very begining of your code (before setting the wsdl in SOAP::Lite) :

```
$SOAP::Constants::PREFIX_ENV = 'SOAP-ENV';
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change the prefix (and also many other things) - this didn't help. I just can't generate XML that doesn't break the data format. Maybe some other time I'll spend a day or two to learn thoroughly this Perl module, but just now I already have perfectly working out-of-the-box solution in PHP. I'll just call the php script from Perl code.

Answer (score 0):

Code with SOAP::Lite is quite simple:

```
$uri = 'http://example.test';
$proxy = 'https://www.just-example.test/dir/JustTest/Service.asmx';

$client = SOAP::Lite->new(
              uri   => $uri,
              proxy => $proxy,
             );

$client->autotype(0);
$client->readable(1);
$client->ns($uri,'ns1');
$client->envprefix('SOAP-ENV');

$params = SOAP::Data->name(TestParam => 0)->prefix('ns1');

$data = $client->ExampleMethod($params);
```